# react native: Is there a way to make the "checkVal" function work according to the logic I wrote down?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-redux

I tried to write the function "**checkVal**" but it does not work for me.
I would be happy to some help with this.

**This is what the function "checkVal" should do:**

**1.** The user should be allowed only 2 attempts to enter a value of the "TextInput" field.

**2.** If the condition is met for the first time then "Teken_1_Modal" should be displayed and also a checkbox should be displayed below the TextInput field - if the user has marked the checkbox then "Teken_2_Modal" and also "Dial" will appear.
Once the checkbox is checked then the check cannot be removed afterwards ..

**3.** If the condition is met a second time then "Teken_2_Modal" and also "Dial" must be displayed .

```
import CheckBox from '@react-native-community/checkbox';
import { Teken_1_Modal } from '../components/Teken_1_Modal';
import { Teken_2_Modal } from '../components/Teken_2_Modal';
import { Dial } from '../components/Dial';

function App() {
  const [toggleCheckBox, setToggleCheckBox] = useState(false)


//////////START FUNCTION ////////////////////////
function checkVal() {
      const [count, setCount] = useState(0) // flag, can be between 0 to 2, will be reset after press it.
      // The flag is per parameter {requestId} !!
    if (count == 2) {
      return; // exit the function
    }else{ 
      count ++
    if (item.Immediate_Report_Min == null && item.Immediate_Report_Max !== null && inputValue > 
        item.Immediate_Report_Max) ||
       (item.Immediate_Report_Min !== null && item.Immediate_Report_Max == null && inputValue < 
        item.Immediate_Report_Min) ||
      (item.Immediate_Report_Min !== null && item.Immediate_Report_Max !== null && (inputValue > max || 
       inputValue < min))
    // then
    if (count == 1) {// first try
     <Teken_1_Modal />
      setToggleCheckBox(toggleCheckBox);  //in case of Check of the checkBox so u cant uncheck after !!
   // then
      if (count == 2) {// second try   
      <Teken_2_Modal />
      < Dial />
      setToggleCheckBox(toggleCheckBox);  
    }
////////////////////END FUNCTION////////////////////////////


  return (
      <View>
        <View style={styles.ParamViewInput}>
          <TextInput
            style={styles.ParamTextInput}
            blurOnSubmit={true}
            autoCapitalize="none"
            autoCorrect={false}
            keyboardType="number-pad"
            maxLength={6}
            placeholder="input.."
            onChangeText={(text) => onChangeInput(index, text)}
            value={inputMeasurement[index]}
            onBlur={() => console.log('onBlur for index:', index)}
          />
          <Text style={styles.label_C}>{item.Parameter_Units}</Text>
          <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => {
            setHistory_ModalVisible(item.Parameter_Code);
          }} style={styles.ParameterUnit}>
            <Text style={styles.Hlable}>H</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
          {<Text style={styles.SignText}>{icon}</Text>}
        </View>
        <CheckBox
         disabled={false}
         value={toggleCheckBox}
         onValueChange={(newValue) => setToggleCheckBox(newValue)}
         />
        <History_Modal reqId={requestId} paramId={item.Parameter_Code}
          modalVisible={isHistory_ModalVisible == item.Parameter_Code}
          setModalVisible={() => {
            setHistory_ModalVisible(false);
          }}
        />
      </View>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming checkVal is something you are calling multiple times after something is being updated, you should not have a useState() inside the function. Since once the function is called and disposed, the count state is also disposed.

Hooks should only be used inside functional components, not some other function that you call multiple times upon users action.

Put the `const [count, setCount] = useState(0);` outside along with `toggleCheckBox`

Then try to achieve the same effect. Also where are trying to call setCount and where are you using count ? Does it need to be in state ?